# Find the sum of each row with the same date and insert it at the end of the date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to find all the data that have the same date and add their total collections and deposit. I have done it in sql but I think it's also doable in javascript. That way, my query would be less, but I'm having a hard time to find the right way to do it using javascript.

This is my sample data:

```
this.GeneratedFinancialReport = [
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "10", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "15"},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "15"},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "30", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "10"},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "40"},
]
```

[image]

I want it to have a row at every end of the date which returns the sum of collections and deposit like:

```
this.GeneratedFinancialReport = [
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "10", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "15"},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "15"},
  {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Total", collection: 30, deposit: "30"},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "30", deposit: null},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "10"},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "40"},
  {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Total", collection: 50, deposit: "50"},
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved through `Array.reduce`.

Logic

- Loop through `GeneratedFinancialReport` array.
- Check if the accumulator already have a node with the date of current node
- If the accumulator already have a node of same date, update the `collection` and `deposit` value of that node.
- Or if the node doesnot exust, push the node to accumulator with numeric value for `collection` and `deposit`

```js
const GeneratedFinancialReport = [
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "10", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "15" },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "15" },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "30", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "10" },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "40" },
]
const combiedResult = GeneratedFinancialReport.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const nodeFromAcc = acc.find((node) => node.date === curr.date);
  if (nodeFromAcc) {
    nodeFromAcc.collection += curr.collection ? Number(curr.collection) : 0;
    nodeFromAcc.deposit += curr.deposit ? Number(curr.deposit) : 0;
  } else {
    const currentNode = { ...curr, collection: curr.collection ? Number(curr.collection) : 0, deposit: curr.deposit ? Number(curr.deposit) : 0 }
    acc.push(currentNode);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(combiedResult);
```

**Edit**

Inorder it insert the result just after the original loop, follow the below logic.

**Logic**

- Using `Array.reduce` group the data in the following format

  ```
   {
     date: '', // Holds the unique date
     Values: [], // Holds the list of value for the unique date
     collection: 0, // Sum of collection for the date
     deposit: 0, // Sum of deposit for the date
   }
  ```
- See the output of first console for the final value that is bing hold in this.
- This will group the data with date will be stored in date key, list of data for the date will be stored in `values` key, sum of `collection` and `deposit` for those will be stored in respective keys.
- After grouping this run an another `Array.reduce` to join the above structire into a single list. For that loop through the above array, store the values against each date in an array, after that push the value corresponding to summation node after pushing the list of values.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const GeneratedFinancialReport = [
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "10", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "15" },
  { date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "15" },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "30", deposit: null },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "10" },
  { date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "40" },
];

const grouppedValue = GeneratedFinancialReport.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const nodeFromAcc = acc.find((node) => node.date === curr.date);
  if(nodeFromAcc) {
    nodeFromAcc.values.push(curr);
    nodeFromAcc.collection += curr.collection ? Number(curr.collection) : 0;
    nodeFromAcc.deposit += curr.deposit ? Number(curr.deposit) : 0;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      date: curr.date,
      values: [curr],
      collection: curr.collection ? Number(curr.collection) : 0, 
      deposit: curr.deposit ? Number(curr.deposit) : 0,
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log('The list groupped with date', JSON.stringify(grouppedValue));

const output = grouppedValue.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc = acc.concat(curr.values.map((node) => node));
  acc.push({
    date: curr.date,
    name_of_collection: "Total",
    collection: curr.collection,
    deposit: curr.deposit,
  })
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log('');
console.log('');
console.log('Final Output', JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: this is correct but I want the result to be inserted in the original object right after the last unique date.

Comment: @KapitanTeemo please check the updated solution now. I have added your requirement in the EDIT section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your data using `array#reduce` and add `collection` and `deposit` of same date in an object accumulator.

```js
const generatedFinancialReport = [ {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "10", deposit: null}, {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null}, {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "15"}, {date: "2021-08-02", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "15"}, {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "20", deposit: null}, {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)", collection: "30", deposit: null}, {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Payment", collection: null, deposit: "10"}, {date: "2021-08-03", name_of_collection: "Ending Balance", collection: null, deposit: "40"}],
      result = Object.values(generatedFinancialReport.reduce((r, {date, name_of_collection, collection, deposit}) => {
        r[date] ??= {date, name_of_collection, collection: 0, deposit: 0};
        r[date].collection += +collection;
        r[date].deposit += +deposit;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I get an error 'Expression expected.' in ??=.

Comment: what does the '??=' mean? what is that operator called?

Comment: ??= is [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Instead of `??=`, you can use `||=`.

Comment: I don't know why but either of the 2 gives me error. It doesn't seem to work in angular.

Comment: Can you try this `r[date] = r[date] || {date, name_of_collection, collection: 0, deposit: 0};`

Comment: it worked, thanks! now I just need to find out how to push the result in the original object respectively.

Comment: You can do `[...generatedFinancialReport, ...result]`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script >

//Group By Function just like SQL

const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
    }, {});
};

//Reducer function to get sum of collections and deposits

const getTotal = function(total, num) {

    let n = 0;
    let ttl = 0;

    if (!Number.isNaN(total)) {
        ttl = total;
    }

    if (!Number.isNaN(num)) {
        n = num;
    }

    return ttl + n;
}

function altClick(event) {

    report = [{
            date: "2021-08-02",
            name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)",
            collection: "10",
            deposit: null
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-02",
            name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)",
            collection: "20",
            deposit: null
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-02",
            name_of_collection: "Payment",
            collection: null,
            deposit: "15"
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-02",
            name_of_collection: "Ending Balance",
            collection: null,
            deposit: "15"
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            name_of_collection: "Payment of Advance Payment - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)",
            collection: "20",
            deposit: null
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            name_of_collection: "Delivery - Mail - Juan Delar Cruz (EMP-0000001)",
            collection: "30",
            deposit: null
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            name_of_collection: "Payment",
            collection: null,
            deposit: "10"
        },
        {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            name_of_collection: "Ending Balance",
            collection: null,
            deposit: "40"
        },
    ]



    let groubedDate = groupBy(report, 'date');

    let keys = Object.keys(groubedDate)
    let total_list = [];

    for (let key of keys) {
        let list = groubedDate[key]

        let collections = list.map(x => parseFloat(x["collection"]))
        let deposits = list.map(x => parseFloat(x["deposit"]))

        let total_collection = collections.reduce(getTotal);
        let total_deposit = deposits.reduce(getTotal);

        ttl_obj = {}
        ttl_obj['date'] = key;
        ttl_obj['name_of_collection'] = 'Total';
        ttl_obj['collection'] = total_collection;
        ttl_obj['deposit'] = total_deposit;

        total_list.push(ttl_obj);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(total_list))
}

</script>

<button id="btn_0" class="button19" onclick="altClick(event)"><img id="myImage_0" src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/kmanha.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>KM-HA8</button>
```

-----------Output-----------------

[{"date":"2021-08-02","name_of_collection":"Total","collection":30,"deposit":30},{"date":"2021-08-03","name_of_collection":"Total","collection":50,"deposit":50}]